# Key sequence ambiguous in Konsole

Tags: kde, konsole, dolphin

My Arch Linux machine has KDE Plasma desktop installed and I'm using Konsole as a terminal. In Konsole, when I highlight text and press Ctrl+Shift+C on my keyboard to copy it, I get this popup message.

```
The key sequence 'Ctrl+Shift+C' is ambiguous. Use 'Configure Shortcuts'
from the 'Settings' menu to solve the ambiguity.
No action will be triggered.
```

The Konsole version is v20.08.0-1.

UPDATE: This only occurs in a a terminal I open in a Dolphin folder. When I open a Konsole terminal alone, Ctrl+Shift+C copies correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with Dolphin. For Dolphin `Ctrl+Shift+C` — is shortcut for *«Copy location»* action. You can reassign it to `None` or to other key sequence. `Ctrl+Shift+L` works fine for me.

<s>I suppose, it is only Arch \ Manjaro problem. There is no such problem at least on Kubuntu and Fedora. But «Copy location» is also absent.</s>

**UPD:**

- «Copy location» was added in [86e3b82e](https://github.com/KDE/dolphin/commit/86e3b82efbbcdb287773cdaf6a5f4c1c22bb9fc6) on Jun 29, 2020:
- There is a Dolphin 20.08 bug: [Ctrl+Shift+C triggers an ambiguous shortcut popup](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=426461).

**So, what to do before it'll be fixed:**

1. Run Dolphin.
2. Go to «Settings» Menu.
3. Click «Configure Keyboard Shortcuts …».
4. Search «Copy location».
5. Assigned the «Custom» shortcut.

---

Additionally, you can save your shortcut scheme for future:

1. Within «Configure Keyboard Shortcut» dialog click «Manage Schemes».
2. Click «More Actions» → «Export Schemes …»
3. Save it in some place on your device.

   - For example my scheme file is: [gist: Manjaro KDE shortcuts for Dolphin](https://gist.github.com/w495/0f1c83ce6612f9c617150c8a13b95230)
4. Within «Configure Keyboard Shortcut / Manage Schemes» сlick «New».
5. Set the name for your new scheme.

   - It it'll be the empty scheme without shortcuts
6. Then import your previously exported scheme.

Moreover, you can check you local shortcut configuration with:

```bsh
grep 'Ctrl+Shift+C' -r ~/.local/ -r ~/.config/
```

For me:

- Konsole: `~/.local/share/konsole/shortcuts/Default`.
  Shortcuts is placed into «Default» profile config.
- Dolphin: `~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/dolphin/dolphinui.rc`.

But your locations may be different. For more details see this thread on KDE forum:

- [Where the configuration file to store keyboard shortcuts](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=151477#p398067)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that this is also a global shortcut or a Kwin shortcut. Open System Settings ⇒ Shortcuts and find it there.

Lastly you may have assigned two different actions to the same shortcut within Konsole in which case

> Use 'Configure Shortcuts' from the 'Settings' menu to solve the ambiguity.

Comment: When I open "System settings" and click "Shortcuts," what should I look for? I don't see any Ctrl+Shift+C shortcut in "Kwin"